# Unexpected results in calling a variable in the context of a function that uses biomaRt library

Tags: r

I have a general question which I think comes down to some kind of scoping issue.

Below is a snippet of a formula that makes use of biomaRt's getSequence() function. The user enters into the custom function (1) the gene name, and optionally (2) number of base pairs upstream to import.

```
# Load libraries
library(biomaRt)
# Let's make a custom "getSequence" function
getUpstream <- function(x, bp.upstream = 50){
    bp.upstream <- bp.upstream
    ensembl <- useMart("ensembl", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
    upstream.master <- NULL
    for(i in x){
        upstream.i <- getSequence(id = i,
            type = "hgnc_symbol",
            seqType = "coding_gene_flank",
            upstream = bp.upstream,
            mart = ensembl
        )
        upstream.master <- rbind(upstream.master, upstream.i)
    }
    return(upstream.master)
}
```

Say I run a search using this function without specifying the number of base pairs upstream, such as:

```
getUpstream("NOTCH4")
```

Unexpectedly, the function does not work without the line:

```
bp.upstream <- bp.upstream
```

Other lines such as print(bb.upstream) will make the code work also.

I thought that bp.upstream would get defined when I call the function and therefore would set upstream=50 once getSequence is called. Can anyone please help me understand why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a workaround to avoid the scope problem.

```
# Load libraries
library(biomaRt)
# Let's make a custom "getSequence" function
 getUpstream <- function(x, bp.upstream = 50){
  ensembl <- useMart("ensembl", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
  upstream.master <- lapply(x, function(i,stream)
                         getSequence(id = i,
                              type = "hgnc_symbol",
                              seqType = "coding_gene_flank",
                              upstream = stream,
                              mart = ensembl),stream=bp.upstream)


  upstream.master
}
```